# react-navigation "go back" to previous screen in another StackNavigator (v5)

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, expo

In react-navigation v5, I have 2 stacks and I navigate from one stack to another stack.

How can you navigate or "go back" to the screen in the previous stack?

Answer (score 3):

Use the `navigation` prop to go back to the previous stack screen.

```
this.props.navigation.goBack()
```

Check out the Office Doc for more options- https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-prop

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why doesn't the menu/header show the "< Back" automatically in this case of navigating from one stack to the next?

Comment: It should show automatically unless you have set `headerShown: false` manually in `options` of `Stack.Screen`.

Comment: It does not show. It only shows when navigating from within the current stack.

Comment: Did you use `createStackNavigator`? see this - https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-navigator/

If that's not the case then you have to provide a reproducible example for me to check.

Comment: From the official doc of Stack navigator - `headerShown: Whether to show or hide the header for the screen. The header is shown by default unless headerMode was set to none. Setting this to false hides the header.`

Comment: No, the header is not hidden, here is a snack showing the example: https://snack.expo.io/@coryrobinson42/1cd250

Comment: you are using `createDrawerNavigator`. It doesn't provide back-button by default. You have to do it manually - https://reactnavigation.org/docs/header-buttons
or,
use DrawerNavigator with StackNavigator - https://gist.github.com/Maluen/878d94c01cc1d62ee5d84dcbac8da4ce

Comment: In v5 of react-navigation you cannot do what your Gist is showing, you have to use JSX elements like React components.